# Growing and planting a beautyberry tree from seed

Tags: trees, shrubs, germination, transplanting, propagation

I recently collected some [beautyberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callicarpa) seeds from a neighbouring tree. How long does it usually take to see the seeds germinate? What is the recommended age and process for moving the new growth into the garden?

Comment: Any idea which variety of Callicarpa you took the seeds from? Are you in the States?

Comment: At least some of these have a cold requirement: https://www.plant-world-seeds.com/store/view_seed_item/2169

Comment: It must not be too tricky as the nearby woods is full of American Beauty Berry that seeded themselves.